# How do I have mails to a specific address trigger actions on a web server?

Tags: apache, email

What I'm trying to do is figure up how I can configure a mail server such that mails to a specific address will trigger certain actions- e.g. inserting the subject line into a MySQL database, etc. This is for a web app in LAMP- basically I want people to be able to add things automatically via email if they'd rather do that than use the web interface. Kind of like how e.g. with Evernote you can send a mail to your custom address to add a note that way.

I realize this is a pretty vague question, what I'm looking for is a general place to start looking and learning. I'm reasonably familiar with website tech but when it comes to mail servers I'm completely clueless.  I'm not looking for any specific implementation: Rather I just want to know what are the basics I need familiarize myself to be able to attack the problem.

Comment: This depends upon the mail-server used -- some can deliver to drop-of directory spools while others use the "standard" [mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) system for delivery. Another approach that could be considered is just using POP access to the SMTP server. Normally this pickup would be done based on a "pull" (e.g. a cron that checks for mail every minute), but there may be some integrated/coupled approaches that can "push".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to trigger actions "in realtime" you best work with your own mailserver and use something like procmail: Here is an example from the procmail faq how to trigger actions on incoming mails: http://porkmail.org/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#rtfm

But if you can avoid this, just let the fun stuff of mailserver work handle your provider and scan one or more mailboxes via cron-job (on linux/unix) triggered scripts. A cronjob could e.g. be a command line PHP script or a wget script that does a HTTP request on your webserver script to start the action. Your script reads the actual mails via something like http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-pop3.php
(Try to avoid importing the same mail twice e.g. by relying on the message id of the mail or by creating SHA1/MD5 hashes on parts or the body of the mail).

A lot of ticket systems work like this (for example OTRS: http://otrs.org/downloads).

Comment: I was going to give this +1 for suggesting using procmail - but changed my mind when you stated that this should be avoided in preference to repeatedly polling the mailbox (probably via POP or IMAP). NO! handling the message synchronously on arrival is the right solution!

Comment: No, it's not the "right" solution per se. If you go the "on demand" path you need a lot of knowledge about the security context, workarounds in situations your database connection is not available (but mails still pouring in), avoiding memory leaks, keep an eye on procmail/scripting language updates and so on. When running long running FCGI processes, e.g., and having IMAP, you come near to that without having to master mail servers.

Answer (score 1):

This is traditionally handled on unix-like systems using [fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) and/or [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/).